# Is there a way to use Twitter 2.0 as a Flume Source?

Tags: twitter, twitter-api-v2, flume-twitter

TwitterSource from Apache Flume only supports v1 endpoints. I need a work around to using Twitter as the source for Apache Flume.

This is the error which pops up when I use the Flume, firehose class
2023-03-18 00:38:03,290 ERROR twitter.TwitterSource: Exception while streaming tweets
https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/sample.json?stall_warnings=true
Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=d0031b0b or
http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=1db75522
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[d0031b0b-1db75522 db667dea-99334ae6 db667dea-99334ae4], statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.3}
at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:192)
at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:61)
at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:89)
at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl.getSampleStream(TwitterStreamImpl.java:176)
at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl$4.getStream(TwitterStreamImpl.java:164)
at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl$TwitterStreamConsumer.run(TwitterStreamImpl.java:462)

I used a Kafka topic as the twitter Source but i want to directly stream tweets from Twitter API.